# Does the following sequence converge?

Tags: analysis, inequality

Suppose $a_i>0$ for all $i$, $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}{n}\to \infty$ and p>1. Let $$y_n = \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i)^p}{n^{p-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i^p)}.$$ Is $y_n$ monotonic? How can you prove or disprove this? Otherwise, can it be shown that $y_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$? If we need to make additional assumptions, what are they?

Comment: I don't think $y_n$ is monotonic. And also, if you let $a_n=1$ for all $n$, then $y_n=1$.

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence $\{a_n\}$ stays extremely close to zero for many consecutive values of $n$, say for any $n\in[M,2M]$, then $y_{M+k}$, regarded as a function of $k$, decreases. Assume then that $a_{2M+r}=r$ for any $r\geq 1$: you have that $y_{2M+r}$ behaves like:
$$\frac{(p+1)(r^2/2)^p}{(2M+r)^{p-1} r^{p+1}}\sim\frac{p+1}{2^p},\tag{1}$$
hence if $y_{2M}$ is less than $\frac{p+1}{2^{p+1}}$ the sequence cannot be monotonic.

Due to the Holder inequality we have:
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^p \leq n^{p-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^p, $$
i.e. $y_n\leq 1$, but this holds as en equality if $a_1=a_2=\ldots$, hence $y_n$ may not converge to $1$ when $n$ tends to infinity. Moreover, you can build sequences such that the limit $\lim_{n\to+\infty} y_n$ exists and it is any number in the $[0,1]$ interval, just like we have done in $(1)$ by choosing $a_{2M+r}=r^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha=1$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I was a bit unclear initially. I'm especially interested in the convergence part, and also in doing this in more generality if possible.